# Share http session between two servlet in different domains

Tags: session, servlets, httpsession

I'm working on a java application which running in one server with two different domain names: aaa.com and bbb.net.
I have a servlet (A) running on aaa.com/A and another servlet (B) running on bbb.net/B. 
In servlet A, in doGet() function:

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("test", "hello");
req.sendRedirect("bbb.net/B");
```

In servlet B, in doGet() function:

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession();
// session: null
```

I want to get test variable of servlet A in servlet B but it seems that variable lost. For some reason, I dont't want to use parameters.
I refered this site (https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/sendredirect-forward-jsp-servlet.html) and there are two points which make me think it's possible to retrieve variable from servlet A in servlet B:

1. In case of sendRedirect request is transfer to another resource to **different domain** or different server for futher processing.
2. But in sendRedirect if we want to use we **have to store the data in session** or pass along with the URL.

Do I understand anything wrong here?

Comment: If you call `sendRedirect` to other domain, new session will be created for the target domain. If you `sendRedirect` to same domain you can get back the same session instance. So sending parameter will be your best bet. In point 2 is only valid for same domain redirection.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I understood. But get URL is limited (~2000 characters), and if parameter data is too long, is there any way to solve it?

Comment: You can redirect to a dummy jsp page which have form submitting to `servletB` and do form submit on document load. This isn't really a good practice but should do the trick. 
TL;DR; use POST submit.

Comment: It seems that is the only way for this. Thank you :)